# How to control mac default icon size 128x128 display through Install4j settings

Tags: install4j

We have a installer image with 48X48 for our App but in MAC its stretching up to 128X128 due mac default icon size and that causing image blurring.

we have tried with an image 128X128 and there is no stretching/blurring but it looks too big. so we are looking for some settings to control the MAC default icon size thorough install4j or any other solution.

in the past, with install4j 6.x we have used the default image that comes with install4j and never noticed this issue. 
[Blurry image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDHUE.jpg)

[Image 128X128 - with out blurr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAgpD.jpg/)

[Another image with both on side by side (Default in 6.x Vs nonDefault in 7.x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8GeG.jpg)

Comment: `we have tried with an image 128X128 and there is no stretching/blurring but it looks too big` can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Hope these images helps.. i can upload the image along with the installer/launcher if required.

Comment: So what is the problem with the non-blurry image? You said it looks to big, I cannot see that from the screen shots.

Comment: non-blurry image is default to MAC 128X128 icon size (what ever image we are providing here. since now we have used an image with size 128X128 there is no blurr) and its bigger than what we have used in the past with default install4j image (a computer monitor with keyboard) which is 74X74 in MAC. so we are trying to understand how come install4j  default icon showed perfectly/no-blur with size 74X74 in MAC using install4j 6.x but now MAC is taking precedence and stretching the small image upto 128X128.

Comment: There have been no changes with respect to icons in install4j 7. I still don't understand what the problem is. How can the icon look bigger if the external dimensions are determined by the finder? Do you have screenshots where you can see that one icon is bigger than the other?

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this. for better understanding the issue i have added another image above -  Another image with both on side by side (Default in 6.x Vs nonDefault in 7.x).  Here in 6.x image is not stretched and stayed as 48X48 irrespective of the MAC default icon size (128X128). the same is not true with 7.x if i provide a smaller image its stretching up to MAC default icon size and thats the reason we were end up by providing a bigger size image (its bigger when compared with the install4j default  small image)

Comment: 128x128 is the default size for the icon view in a finder window. If the icon does not have sufficient resolution, it is displayed in a smaller size. Your screenshot shows the view options where you can adjust the maximum size of the icon. I don't see any problem.

Comment: ya.. i can adjust this at my local machine. but is there any way that i can force/control/guide this size through install4j? i mean this will be installed at multiple customer places and we want to keep this size common to  all of our customers through install4j

Comment: OK, I finally understood your question, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you Ingo. waiting to see your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the visual aspects of the folder when the DMG is mounted, you can include a `.DS_Store` file on the "Installer options->Additional files in the DMG" step of the media wizard. The `.DS_Store` file is taken from a folder where you have adjusted the settings accordingly.

The help chapter on [styling DMGs](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/dmgStyling.html) shows you the list of steps.